# AJAX FANCY BOX

Tags: ajax, fancybox

Доброго! Подскажите пожалуйста пример подгрузки страницы из базы по id для fancy box.
По клику на ссылку

Comment: я имею ввиду в базе инфа о станице по id. Можно пример? не получается найти нужного

Comment: @IOleg, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

```
<a class="various fancybox.ajax" data-fancybox-type="ajax" href="/demo/ajax.php">Ajax</a>

$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

Вот это все что требуется от fancybox. А в файле ajax.php загружается инфа о странице по id. Делайте загрузку, это уже не фенсибокса работа.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант, чтобы не ставить каждой ссылке доп.атрибут data-fancybox-type="ajax" можно выполнить такую конструкцию

```
    <a class="need" data-id="2" href="/demo/ajax.php">Дайте 2</a>
        ...
    $('a.need').fancybox({
        type: 'ajax',
        ajax : {
            type    : "POST",
            data    : 'id=' + $(this).attr('data-id')
        }           
    });
```

На /demo/ajax.php будет отправлен POST запрос с id, который указан в data-id

Либо ещё проще

```
<a class="need" href="/demo/ajax.php?id=3">Дайте 3</a>
    ...
$('a.need').fancybox({
    type: 'ajax',
    ajax : {
        type    : "POST",
    }           
});
```